# Express $E(x^{\alpha})$ in terms of $E(e^{-\zeta x})$? to a 1st or second order?

Tags: expected-value, approximation, taylor-series

I have a random variable, $X$, and am able to find $\mathbf{E}(e^{-\zeta X})$ for many $\zeta$ (through the Laplace transform solving an ODE as this actually evolves over time)

Is there any way I can approximate power moments of $X$: i.e. $\mathbf{E}(X^{\alpha})$ where $\alpha$ is not necessarily an integer?  (I realize that this will not always be convergent for higher moments, or necessarily very accurate, especially if $\alpha < 0$ and hence the function is not analytic.  See notes in [When do Taylor series approximations to expectations of (entire) functions converge?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/160764/when-do-taylor-series-approximations-to-expectations-of-entire-functions-conve))

---

I tried to find some transformation of a taylor series, but couldn't figure it out.  What I want to do is avoid solving an ODE in transformed $\log(X)$ variable if I can.

Comment: I think If  $X$ has some specific distributions, such as Gamma distribuiton then $E(X^{\alpha})$ can be analytically expressed but that only for $\alpha$ is a positive integer

Comment: Thanks.  Alas, no chance on an analytic distribution.