# Where does the delta method's name come from?

Tags: terminology, delta-method

Where does the [delta method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_method)'s name come from?

I don't see anything related to "$\epsilon$-$\delta$", nor Dirac delta for example.

Comment: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/delta

Comment: Delta-method is closely related (sometimes synonym) to the concept of propagation of error, e.g. see [this](http://math.arizona.edu/~jwatkins/K2_clt.pdf). The name follows probably from the fact that $\delta$ and $\Delta$ are used to denote error in calculus.

Comment: @Francis So does it come from Taylor series? Since it has that error term?

Comment: @mavavilj: could be, but I haven't found a source to confirm this.

Comment: @Francis Indeed, Taylor series, see my answer edit.

Answer (score 5):

The name "Delta" is from the symbol $\Delta$ for "change" which is used in limit expressions like let $\Delta X_i\rightarrow 0$, where $\Delta X_i=X_{i+1}-X_i$, and also $\Delta$ or lower case "δ" refers to an inexact, non-zero differential equation (i.e., before limits are taken) which reduces in the limits to a [differential equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_equation) the latter using infinitesimals. For example, $\Delta f(x)= f(x+\Delta x)-f(x)$, which reduces to $\partial f$, a vanishingly small differential, for $\Delta x$ sufficiently small. Now sometimes we want to manipulate equations so that we are not dividing or multiplying by zeros, and in that case, we might use the $\Delta $ notation.

The name *delta method*, is probably only used by statisticians. In other contexts, e.g., engineering, physics, it would be more commonly referred to as propagation of error. To see how the error propagation includes the $\Delta$ symbol, see [propagation of error](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/mpc/section5/mpc55.htm).

```
 Edit
```

Error propagation is from Taylor series, [useful examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagation_of_uncertainty#Example_formulas). Indeed, when extended to the first two derivatives of [Taylor series](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/13005/99274), i.e., $\mathbf{Var}[Y]\approx(g'(\mu_X))^2\sigma_{X}^{2}+g'(\mu_X)g''(\mu_X)\mu_3+\frac{1}{4}(g''(\mu_X))^2(\mu_4-\sigma_{X}^{4})$, it becomes more accurate, and I would venture that that is needed when the solution space curvature is of greater magnitude.

BTW, in ancient Greek the letter $\Delta$ was pronounced as a "d" sound and in modern Greek this is a hybrid "d" and "th" sound. The [etymology](https://www.etymonline.com/word/delta) is purported to be as follows,

c. 1200, Greek letter shaped like a triangle, equivalent to our "D," the name from Phoenician daleth "tent door." [Herodotus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herodotus) used it of the mouth of the Nile, and it was so used in English from 1550s; applied to other river mouths from 1790.